# Why ALL styles in my theme.res file have border mode set to top-only?

Tags: codenameone

Today I found out I have all styles, that have set rectangle border, set it's border mode to top-only. When I click to choose other border mode, and confirm OK to Border dialog window, it doesn't change that border mode. It stays top-only. So I can't change border mode.
When I was working with it on Friday, it worked.
Was there a change/update of cn1 framework between Friday-Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently made a [fix for this feature](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/5af1aa727983962078786be2dc19dff77e8efbd4) ([or two fixes](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/010d0805f8bbf977e83a0c474c746f91a5d0ced5)) and it might have broken the designer tool which relied on the original behavior. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) on that so we can keep track of this.

Comment: Done! https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2993
Thanks for info Shai.